# R Fixest Package: IV Estimation Without Further Exogenous Variables

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I intend to run instrumental variable regressions with fixed effects using the `fixest` package's `feols` function. However, I am having issues with the syntax specifying an estimation without further exogenous controls.

Consider the following example:

```
# Load package
require("fixest")

# Load data
df <- airquality
```

I would like to something like the following, i.e. explaining the outcome via the instrumented endogenous variable and fixed effects:

```
feols(Temp | Month + Day | Ozone ~ Wind, df)
```

This, however, produces an error:

```
The dependent variable is a constant. Estimation cannot be done.
```

It only works, when I add further exogenous covariates (as in the documentation's examples):

```
feols(Temp ~ Solar.R | Month + Day | Ozone ~ Wind, df)
```

How do I fix this? How do I run the estimation without further controls, such as `Solar.R` in this case?

Note: I post this on Stack Overflow rather than Cross Validated because the question relates to a coding syntax issue, and not to the econometric techniques underlying the estimations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually there seems to be a misunderstanding on how to write the formula.

The syntax is: `Dep_var ~ Exo_vars | Fixed-effects | Endo_vars ~ Instruments`.

The parts `Fixed-effects` and `Endo_vars ~ Instruments` are optional. On the other hand, the part with `Exo_vars` must **always** be there, be it with only the intercept.

Knowing that, the following works:

```
base = iris
names(base) = c("y", "x1", "x_endo", "x_inst", "fe")

feols(y ~ 1 | x_endo ~ x_inst, base)
#> TSLS estimation, Dep. Var.: y, Endo.: x_endo, Instr.: x_inst
#> Second stage: Dep. Var.: y
#> Observations: 150 
#> Standard-errors: Standard 
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 4.345900    0.08096  53.679 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> fit_x_endo  0.398477    0.01964  20.289 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> RMSE: 0.404769   Adj. R2: 0.757834
#> F-test (1st stage): stat = 1,882.45  , p < 2.2e-16 , on 1 and 148 DoF.
#>         Wu-Hausman: stat =     3.9663, p = 0.048272, on 1 and 147 DoF.

# Same with fixed-effect
feols(y ~ 1 | fe | x_endo ~ x_inst, base)
#> TSLS estimation, Dep. Var.: y, Endo.: x_endo, Instr.: x_inst
#> Second stage: Dep. Var.: y
#> Observations: 150 
#> Fixed-effects: fe: 3
#> Standard-errors: Clustered (fe) 
#>            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> fit_x_endo 0.900061   0.117798  7.6407 0.016701 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> RMSE: 0.333489     Adj. R2: 0.833363
#>                  Within R2: 0.57177 
#> F-test (1st stage): stat = 44.77    , p = 4.409e-10, on 1 and 146 DoF.
#>         Wu-Hausman: stat =  0.001472, p = 0.969447 , on 1 and 145 DoF.
```

Getting back to the original example:

- `feols(Temp | Month + Day | Ozone ~ Wind, df)` means that the dependent variable will be `Temp | Month + Day | Ozone` with the pipe here meaning the logical OR, leading to a 1 for all observations. Hence the error message.
- To fix it and obtain an appropriate behavior, use `feols(Temp ~ 1 | Month + Day | Ozone ~ Wind, df)`.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that the `Exo_vars` argument appears to be mandatory. But I did not know how to overcome it. It is good to know that plugging in a 1 fixes the problem. Nice package, by the way.

Comment: Yes, there's no way around that 1. Thanks!