# Fixed effect instrumental variable (IV) regression with available diagnostic tests

Tags: r, regression, instruments, panel-data, diagnostics

May I please know an R package and code to run fixed effect instrumental variable (IV) regression with available diagnostic tests (e.g., weak instrument test, exogeneity test (using Wu-Hausman), Sargan test)?

I know `plm` code provides the fixed effect IV regressions but its diagnostic tests are not available unfortunately.

Even if I run the `iv_robust` code from `estimatr` package and specify as `diagnostics = TRUE`, it produces a warning message saying

"In iv_robust(.. : Will not return `diagnostics` if `fixed_effects` are used."

So no diagnostics can be run in fixed effect using `iv_robust` code either.

I also have both x and x^2 endogenous variables. I wonder what is the best way to run the fixed effect IV regression and how to do the diagnostic tests for these as well.

Comment: @Helix123 That is only for the pgmm not for plm.

Comment: oh, indeed! deleted my comment.

Comment: @Quinten: That cannot run fixed effect models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a look at the very nice `fixest` package from L. Bergé: [R Fixest Package: IV Estimation Without Further Exogenous Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309126/r-fixest-package-iv-estimation-without-further-exogenous-variables) (For the syntax with IV's).

The `fitstat` function can compute all of your required tests, e.g.

```
fitstat(yourmodel, type = "ivf")
```

or you can put them directly inside the table with `etable`, e.g.

```
library(fixest)
gravity = feols(log(Euros) ~ log(dist_km) | Destination + Origin, trade)


etable(gravity, fitstat = ~  r2 + wald.p + wf)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still not sure whether this works as I see my run time is extremely long only for the feols code itself. The code is still not completing its running. I never experienced this problem when running all other types of IV regressions in R. I also carefully followed the formula syntax as suggested in your link as well. Is there a way to expediate the runtime to see whether I can get desired results?

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://github.com/lrberge/fixest#benchmarking Usually `fixest` is very fast, but it might be that it does not perform so well for IVs.

Comment: I’m sorry to hear that.